# Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource. with Contribute No Delete

Tags: updatelistitems

I am getting this error when User has Contribute No Delete permission and try to update folder under document library.

This is the steps I followed,

1. Create new document library
2. Create folder under document library
3. Update name of the folder and you will see below error

[image]

**Error in ULS**

> *System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)), StackTrace:     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.AddOrUpdateItem(Boolean bAdd, Boolean
>   bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean
>   bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin,
>   Guid newGuidOnAdd, Int32& ulID, Object& objAttachmentNames, Object&
>   objAttachmentContents, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename,
>   Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.UpdateInternal(Boolean bSystem,
>   Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Boolean bMigration,
>   Boolean bPublish, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean
>   bCheckin, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename, Boolean
>   bPreserveItemUIVersion)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.Update()      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.ValidateUpdateListItem_Client(List`1
>   formValues, Boolean bNewDocumentUpdate, String checkInComment)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerStub.SPListItemServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object
>   target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext
>   proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object
>   target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext
>   proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.InvokeMethod(Object
>   obj, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, Boolean& isVoid)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessMethod(XmlElement
>   xe)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessOne(XmlElement
>   xe)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessStatements(XmlNode
>   xe)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessExceptionHandlingScope(XmlElement
>   xe)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessOne(XmlElement
>   xe)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessStatements(XmlNode
>   xe)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.Process()      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestServiceImpl.ProcessQuery(Stream
>   inputStream, IList`1 pendingDisposableContainer)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestService.ProcessQuery(Stream
>   inputStream)      at SyncInvokeProcessQuery(Object , Object[] ,
>   Object[] )      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext
>   request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext
>   currentOperationContext)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext
>   request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult
>   result)      at
>   System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult
>   result)      at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean
>   completedSynchronously)      at
>   System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)      at
>   System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean
>   canDispatchOnThisThread)      at
>   System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, Action
>   dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor`3.Enqueue(QueueItemType
>   item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
>
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.CompleteParseAndEnqueue(IAsyncResult
>   result)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.HandleParseIncomingMessage(IAsyncResult
>   result)      at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.SyncContinue(IAsyncResult
>   result)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginProcessInboundRequest(ReplyChannelAcceptor
>   replyChannelAcceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`1.ProcessHttpContextAsync()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.BeginHttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext
>   context, Action acceptorCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object
>   state)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult
>   result)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object
>   state)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.AspNetPartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)      at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequestWithFlow(Object
>   state)      at
>   System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32
>   errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
>   at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32
>   error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)      at
>   System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32
>   errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)*

**Permissions Contribute No Delete**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am assuming you are using a custom permission, please capture some screens on the permission level that was configured

Comment: There might be some permission issues, is that you have breaked permissions of that document library? Please check the site permissions to.

Comment: @Joe sorry for not giving you details about permissions. Updated my question with permissions.

Comment: @NiranjanKulkarni updated

Comment: Looks like SharePoint requires delete permission in order to rename file/folder. I gave delete permission and it started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Microsoft design, folders requires Delete permission, this is due to the WEBDAV behavior. You can read more on this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2505742?wa=wsignin1.0).

For regular custom list (without folder), delete may be omitted.